# Wie heisst "kitchen island" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie bezeichnet man ein *kitchen island* auf Deutsch?

Ein *kitchen island* ist eine Art Schrank in der Mitte der Küche. Manche *kitchen islands* haben einen Herd eingebaut, andere nur Schränke. Sie werden als Arbeitsfläche oder Anrichte und (wenn mit Herd) zum Kochen genutzt. Es sind keine Tische; meistens haben sie Schranktüren unter der Arbeitsfläche / unter dem Herd. Man kann sie nich bewegen; sie sind fest installiert.

"Kücheninsel" klingt etwas lieblos wort-wörtlich aus dem Englischen rübergezogen.

Leo kennt den Begriff nicht und in den Foren finde ich auch nichts überzeugendes.

Wikipedia hat den Begriff "Kücheninsel" nur unter Küchenarbeitsplatte, und das ist nicht das Gleiche.

Comment: Kücheninsel ist ein korrekter deutscher Begriff, der eine kleine Küche im Raum beschreibt. Leider kenne ich das englische `kitchen island` nicht und kann deshalb die Frage nicht beantworten. Aber ich würde bei [Google nach Kücheninsel suchen](https://www.google.de/search?q=k%C3%BCcheninsel) und mal prüfen, ob es dem englischen `kitchen island` entspricht (z.B bei [Ikea](http://www.ikea.com/ms/de_DE/rooms_ideas/small_spaces/small_country_kitchen.html))

Comment: Danke, ich hab die Frage um eine Erklärung ergänzt. Googles Bildersuche zeigt für Kücheninsel kitchen islands an. Vielleicht ist Kücheninsel doch der Begriff, den ich suche.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kücheninsel ist ein korrekter deutscher Begriff, der dem entspricht was in der Frage beschrieben wird.

Eine [Googlesuche](https://www.google.de/search?q=k%C3%BCcheninsel) listet viele Händler dazu
(z.B bei [Ikea](http://www.ikea.com/ms/de_DE/rooms_ideas/small_spaces/small_country_kitchen.html))

Die Beschreibung einer [Immobilienmaklerplattform](http://wohnen.immonet.de/kueche/kuecheninsel.html):

> Spätestens seit die „Kochinseln“ in großen Küchen Einzug halten, steht sich hier niemand mehr im Weg. [..] Durch eine Kochinsel wird selbst das Wohnzimmer zum zentralen Anziehungspunkt. [..] Eine gute Kochinsel braucht Platz – so werden diese gern schon mal in ein Wohnzimmer gebaut, wenn es sich um einen loftähnlichen Raum handelt.
>
> Und die zu kleine Küche?
> Zum Gästezimmer wird sie umgebaut, inklusive Wasseranschluss! Kochinseln – ästhetisch und funktional Inseln, die auch ohne Wasser treiben! Und Inseln, die wir selbst erschaffen, denn Individualität wird groß geschrieben. Ob rund, quadratisch oder rechteckig. Der Vielfalt sind kaum Grenzen gesetzt. Je nach Geschmack gibt es viele Möglichkeiten: von der Variante, den Küchenblock dezent in das Ambiente zu integrieren bis hin zum auffallend gestalteten Blickfang. Die Küche wird in Zukunft zum sozialen und funktionalen Ort – ein Spiegel der gesellschaftlichen und technischen Entwicklung.

Ein [Küchenlexikon](http://www.lex-kitchen.com/sd-insel) geht auf die UNterschide zwischen Kochinsel und Wandküche ein:

> Eine Inselküche ist das Herzstück vieler Eigenheimbesitzer. Sie betont die Wichtigkeit, die wir dem stilvollen Kochen beimessen. Und sie weist viele Vorteile gegenüber der herkömmlichen Küche auf: kürzere Wege, zusätzliche Abstellflächen und von allen Seiten bequem erreichbare Arbeitsflächen. Hier können zwei oder mehr Personen ideal zusammenarbeiten, ohne sich gegenseitig zu behindern.

Ein [Küchenplaner](http://www.kuechen-atlas.de/kuechenplanung/planungsanleitung/) listet unter `4. Schritt: Für eine Küchenform entscheiden` verschidene Küchenformen, am Ende kommt die `Insel-Küche`.

Comment: Sagt man Kochinsel, wenn ein Herd drin ist, und Kücheninsel, wenn nicht? Oder sind beide Begriffe völlig austauschbar?

Comment: @fifaltra Hab vor kurzem aus aktuellem Anlass etwas Online-Zeit im kuechen-forum verbracht, wo auch die Vor- und Nachteile der verschiedenen Kücheninselformen (Kochinsel, Spülinsel, reine Arbeitsinsel) diskutiert wurden. Kochinsel ist es also nur, wenn ein Kochfeld drin ist (oder Backofen kann auch gerne woanders sein).

Comment: @arne.b das ist ja eigentlich noch eine eigene Antwort wert, da ja in der Frage auch danach gefragt war, wie man das ganze nennt, wenn es nur eine Arbeitsplatte hat und keinen Herd.

Answer (score 2):

Man findet eine Reihe von Begriffen für diese spezielle Form einer Küche, in der der Herd und manchmal auch die Spüle von allen Seiten zugänglich im Zentrum der Küche steht.

Der häufigste Begriff ist die **Kochinsel**:

> Viele ambitionierte Hobbyköche träumen von ihr, aber auch für die Familienküche ist sie perfekt: die Kochinsel. So haben Sie selbst beim Spaghetti-Kochen die Kleinen immer im Blick.<sup>[Schöner Wohnen](http://www.schoener-wohnen.de/einrichten/meine-traumkueche/100305-alles-fuer-die-familienkueche-14.html)</sup>

[image] <sup>[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einbauk%C3%BCche)</sup>

Man findet aber auch die **"Kücheninsel"** und als spezielle Küchenform die **"Inselküche"** als gut verständliche und somit akzeptiere Wortbildungen.